# spring boot use redis as cache, I can use keyGenerator but use key fails

Tags: spring, caching, spring-boot, redis

When I use redis as my spring boot project's cache ,I found that if I use @Cacheable(value = "user",keyGenerator="keyGenerator") it does work,BUT I switch to @Cacheable(value = "user",key = "#p0"), it doesn't work!! I try my best to solve the problem, but I fail... So I need you help!
Thank you first!
RedisConfig:

```
import cn.limbo.utils.HashValueRedisObjectSerializer;
import cn.limbo.utils.SampleKeyGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

/**
 * redis 配置
 * Created by limbo on 2017/4/21.
 */

@Configuration
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int port ;

    @Value("${spring.redis.timeout}")
    private int timeout;

    @Bean(name = "keyGenerator")
    public KeyGenerator KeyGenerator(){
        return new SampleKeyGenerator();
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new 
        JedisConnectionFactory();
        redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
        redisConnectionFactory.setPort(port);
        return redisConnectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate){
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new 
        RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String,String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf){
        StringRedisTemplate template = new StringRedisTemplate(cf);
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new 
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(Object.class);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

  om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL,JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        om.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(om);

        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        template.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new HashValueRedisObjectSerializer());

        return template;
    }

}
```

User.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by limbo on 2017/4/21.
 */
public class User implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Long id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            '}';
    }

}
```

UserService.java

```
import cn.limbo.domain.User;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by limbo on 2017/4/21.
 */
public interface UserService {

    /**
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    User findUserById(Long id);

    /**
     * @return
     */
    List<User> findAllUser();

    /**
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    Long saveUser(User user);

    /**
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    Long updateUser(User user);

    /**
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    Long deleteUser(Long id);

}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
import cn.limbo.dao.UserDao;
import cn.limbo.domain.User;
import cn.limbo.service.UserService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheConfig;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by limbo on 2017/4/21.
 */
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {"userCache"}) //可以指定key的生成器 如：keyGenerator = "keyGenerator" 这个与key是互斥的
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Cacheable(key = "#p0")
    public User findUserById(Long id) {
        return userDao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable
    public List<User> findAllUser() {
        return userDao.findAllUser();
    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(key = "#p0.id")
    public Long saveUser(User user) {
        return userDao.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(key = "#p0.id")
    public Long updateUser(User user) {
        return userDao.updateUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(key = "#p0") //移除指定key的数据
    public Long deleteUser(Long id) {
        return userDao.deleteUser(id);
    }
}
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to        java.lang.String

at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer.serialize(StringRedisSerializer.java:33)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheKey.serializeKeyElement(RedisCacheKey.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheKey.getKeyBytes(RedisCacheKey.java:49)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$1.doInRedis(RedisCache.java:176)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$1.doInRedis(RedisCache.java:172)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:207)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:157)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:172)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:133)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:71)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:537)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:503)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:389)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
at cn.limbo.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$817ccd4.findUserById(<generated>)
at cn.limbo.ApplicationTests.test(ApplicationTests.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Now I found above problem cause by using a wrong KeySerializer,BUT here come a new problem.I try to return a pojo written by myself, but IDEA give me wrong message like this:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is     org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.EOFException

at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:82)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache$CacheValueAccessor.deserializeIfNecessary(RedisCache.java:477)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:323)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:133)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:71)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:537)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:503)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:389)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
at cn.limbo.service.impl.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91b4a11c.findUserById(<generated>)
at cn.limbo.ApplicationTests.test(ApplicationTests.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.EOFException
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:78)
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:36)
at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.deserialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:80)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.<init>(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:63)
at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.<init>(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:49)
at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultDeserializer.java:68)
at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.DeserializingConverter.convert(DeserializingConverter.java:73)
... 44 more
```

Comment: There are a bunch of that config that's provided by Spring Boot automatically BTW. Looks like a redis implementation specific thing that doesn't convert the long to String. Weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StringSerializer` used in `template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer())` is only capable of converting `String` into its binary format and back. Therefore is might not be the best choice if you want to use any other type as the `key`, as in the `id`, which seems to be a `Long`.

`GenericToStringSerializer` allows you to benefit from Springs `DefaultConversionService` for key de-/serialization, so you do not have to worry about simple conversions. Maybe the `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` is what you need for more complex cache keys.

For more information on `RedisSerilaizers` please refer to [Spring Data Redis Reference - 5.7. Serializers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer).

BTW - for `@Bean` you do not have to call `afterPropertiesSet()` explicitly - if you do, please make sure you do so *after* setting all properties.

Comment: Sorry, I did what you say but it still have some problems. I solve key serialize, but a value serialize got trouble. I try to return a pojo,but idea give me a error message like this :
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.EOFException

Comment: Do you have cache entries that have not been written with the configured `Jackson2RedisSerializer`? can you point me to an example I can quickly run?

Comment: I give you my github: https://github.com/NetFilx/spring-boot/tree/master/6.springboot-redis-cache/cache-annotations

Comment: Sorry took some time till I got to it. The problem is that `UserServiceImpl.saveUser` return `Long` for the id of the saved user instead of the `User` object. So the value ending up in the cache for a user with eg. id `1` is the actual `id`, in this case `1` instead of the serialized full object. Now any cache lookup, like on `findById` hits the cache entry for the `id` backed by an invalid object. Switching from `Long` to `User` as a return type for the `save` and `update` methods on `UserServiceImpl` should help.

Comment: The configuration for the GenericToStringSerializer looks like this: redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Long>(Long.class));